# Most efficient way to save binary code to file

Tags: c#, encoding, binary

I have a string that only contains `1` and `0` and I need to save this to a .txt-File.
I also want it to be as small as possible. Since I have binary code, I can turn it into pretty much everything. Saving it as binary is not an option, since apparently every character will be a whole byte, even if it's a `1` or a `0`.
I thought about turning my string into an Array of Byte but trying to convert `"11111111"` to `Byte` gave me a `System.OverflowException`.
My next thought was using an ASCII Codepage or something. But I don't know how reliable that is. Alternatively I could turn all of the 8-Bit pieces of my string into the corresponding numbers. 8 characters would turn into a maximum of 3 (255), which seems pretty nice to me. And since I know the highest individual number will be 255 I don't even need any delimiter for decoding. 
But I'm sure there's a better way.
So:
**What exactly is the best/most efficient way to store a string that only contains `1` and `0`?**

Comment: I'd look at `base64`.

Comment: @Shnugo base64 tends to make the data larger, instead of smaller.

Comment: Why not make it bits? So the string `10011001` (8 bytes on disk) would become `0x99` (1 byte on disk). Then after that, use ZIP to compress it even further.

Comment: `"I could turn all of the 8-Bit pieces of my string into the corresponding numbers."` - If you want to get really creative you could probably even store the *entire string* as a single number (then another number for the length) and that's it.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, I know this :-) But the OP wants it as Text... A serie of 0s and 1s won't be the best... And raw binary is not possible as text. There is `base85` which is still a little smaller, but I'd tend to `base64` due to the easier approach...

Comment: @Shnugo ah, so first make it binary and *then* use Base64. That could work yes. If you want to keep it text (but why would you want that?)

Comment: "I need to save this to a .txt-File." Do you actually need it to be text? What restrictions do you have on the characters used, if so - and which encoding? You claim "Saving it as binary is not an option, since apparently every character will be a whole byte, even if it's a 1 or a 0." - that's not really true, as you can create a byte array where each byte is derived from 8 input bits...

Comment: @BartFriederichs, Otherwise there's no need for tricking around :-))

Comment: For whom do you save this ? If it is for a computer change it into bytes and use RLE or something similar. If it is for a human being any "optimization" will make it more difficult to interpret.

Comment: Depending on the nature of your data, Running Length encoding can be useful. But even after that, you wouldn't want to save it as text, since each digit (character) will take more bytes than it really needs.

Comment: To get most compact output, converting each 8 chars into single byte is a best option, IMO. But output won't be human readable (comparing to the source string). Also, where does that string come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could represent all your data as 64 bit integers and then write them to a binary file:

```
// The string we are working with.
string str = @"1010101010010100010101101";
// The number of bits in a 64 bit integer!
int size = 64;
// Pad the end of the string with zeros so the length of the string is divisible by 64.
str += new string('0', str.Length % size);
// Convert each 64 character segment into a 64 bit integer.
long[] binary = new long[str.Length / size]
    .Select((x, idx) => Convert.ToInt64(str.Substring(idx * size, size), 2)).ToArray();
// Copy the result to a byte array.
byte[] bytes = new byte[binary.Length * sizeof(long)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(binary, 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
// Write the result to file.
File.WriteAllBytes("MyFile.bin", bytes);
```

**EDIT:**

If you're only writing 64 bits then it's a one-liner:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("MyFile.bin", BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToUInt64(str, 2)));
```

Comment: Actually arguable better to use this method with bytes instead of long as you will save more space on strings less than 64 in length!

Comment: Well isn't that nice. `"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"` is 8 Bytes large, perfect.

Comment: Cool - see my edit if you're only writing 64 bits - it can be a one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx). Like this:

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create));
```