# Reading editing and writing .bin file in C#

Tags: c#, read-write

I just started my adventure with C#. I want to write simple program that will read .bin file with `OpenFileDialog`, edit part of the file, and save the file with `SaveFileDialog`.

Unfortunately I have some problems probably because I have to learn a lot. Here is part of my code for reading but I have problems to save same file. Basically I think problem is with starting address and ending address because I don't know how to declare this in write function.

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
   
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
        
        br.Close();
    }


    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sfd.ShowDialog();
        BinaryWriter br= new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(sfd.FileName));

        br.Close();
    }
```

I want to write same file back the length of file is always 8192 bytes so start from 0x0000 until 0x1FFF.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You can get the bytes and then save them back to disk, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134383/most-efficient-way-to-save-binary-code-to-file) if that helps.

Comment: In your code you are just opening a file with read or write permission and attaching a binary stream for reading or writing. In neither case are you actually reading or writing any bytes from/to the file.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. There's no code in your question that would attempt to write anything to a file, nor an explanation of what _specifically_ you need help with. Please improve the question.

Answer (score -1):

If I get you correctly, you are trying to read from a file, edit it and save the edited file. I think what you are missing is the actual reading

```
string s = br.ReadString();
```

and writing

```
bw.Write(s);
```

to the file (bw is BinaryWriter).

[check out](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_binary_files.htm) a simple tutorial on reading and writing with binary reader/writer.